# How can I hide the square border around the button

Tags: html, css

[image: Picture]

How can I hide the square border around the button, thanks... and happy new year!
-my code for button

```
.btn-custom {
border-radius: 20px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,yellow,red,yellow);
margin: 13px auto;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
border: hidden;
}

.btn-custom:hover {
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow,red);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **`outline`** property set to **`none`** in this way:

```
.btn-custom{
    outline: none;
}
```

> This will remove the blue border

Comment: Yeah thanks so much, it's fixed <3

Answer (score 0):

Check this script

```
.btn-custom {
border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```